# Switch statement Errors Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

Tags: java

I think the problem is with the switch statement, I keep getting errors in the grade when the grader tries to input 'q.' But no errors in the IDE. [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxtGO.png)
[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTk2Z.png)

```
switch (chV)
{
case 'q':
    System.exit(0);
    break;
case 'c':

    int cntNonWhitespaces = getNumOfNonWSCharacters(textInput);
    System.out.print("Number of non-whitespace characters: " + cntNonWhitespaces);
    break;

case 'w':
    int wordsCount = getNumOfWords(textInput);
    System.out.println("Number of words: " + wordsCount);
    break;

case 'f':
    System.out.println("Enter a word or phrase to be found: ");
    String findS = scannerInput.nextLine();
    int findCount = findText(textInput, findS);
    System.out.println("\"" + findS + "\""+ " " + "instances: " + findCount);

    break;

case 'r':
    String newstringVal = replaceExclamation(textInput);
    System.out.println("Edited textInput: " + newstringVal);
    break;

case 's':
    newstringVal = shortenSpace(textInput);
    System.out.println("Edited textInput:" + newstringVal);
    break;

default:
    System.out.println("Invalid option. Please try again");

}
```

Ill attach the errors I keep getting

Full Code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class AuthoringAssistant {
    public static Scanner scannerInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static String shortenSpace(String textInput) {
        String tempVal = textInput.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");
        return tempVal;
    }
    public static String replaceExclamation(String textInput) {
        String tempVal = textInput.replaceAll("!", ".");
        return tempVal;
    }
    public static int findText(String textInput, String findS) {
        int countVal = 0;
        int it = 0;
        while ((it = textInput.indexOf(findS)) != -1) {
            textInput = textInput.substring(it +
            findS.length());
            countVal += 1;
        }
        return countVal;
    }
    public static int getNumOfWords(String textInput) {
       textInput = shortenSpace(textInput);
       String[] words1 = textInput.split(" ");
       return words1.length;
    }
    public static int getNumOfNonWSCharacters(String textInput) {
        textInput = textInput.trim().replaceAll("\\s", "");
        return textInput.length();
    }
    public static void printMenu() {
        System.out.println("MENU");
        System.out.println("c - Number of non-whitespace characters");
        System.out.println("w - Number of words");
        System.out.println("f - Find text");
        System.out.println("r - Replace all !'s");
        System.out.println("s - Shorten spaces");
        System.out.println("q - Quit");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Choose an option:");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a sample text:");
            System.out.println("");
            String textInput = scannerInput.nextLine();
            System.out.print("You entered: " + textInput);
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("");
            printMenu();
            char chV = scannerInput.nextLine().charAt(0);
            switch (chV)
            {
            case 'q':
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            case 'c':
                int cntNonWhitespaces = getNumOfNonWSCharacters(textInput);
                System.out.print("Number of non-whitespace characters: " + cntNonWhitespaces);
                break;
            case 'w':
                int wordsCount = getNumOfWords(textInput);
                System.out.println("Number of words: " + wordsCount);
                break;
            case 'f':
                System.out.println("Enter a word or phrase to be found: ");
                String findS = scannerInput.nextLine();
                int findCount = findText(textInput, findS);
                System.out.println("\"" + findS + "\""+ " " + "instances: " + findCount);
                break;
            case 'r':
                String newstringVal = replaceExclamation(textInput);
                System.out.println("Edited textInput: " + newstringVal);
                break;
            case 's':
                newstringVal = shortenSpace(textInput);
                System.out.println("Edited textInput:" + newstringVal);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid option. Please try again");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first 2 things you need to learn before you go forward: 1. Learn to properly indent your code.  2. Learn to simplify your problem

Comment: tried your code, it does not give the problem you shown.  You should at least tell us how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you saved??